# Angular - Non child receiving component data is undefined when subscribed to a shared service variable which another component sets

Tags: angular, undefined, angular-services, subscribe

I've been trying to share data between two unrelated components and I've used the shared service approach to this. I've looked at dozens of tutorials and tried many variations of using a service, but no matter what I do, whenever I try to `console.log()` the received data in the receving component the console log dispays nothing.

**The service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StatusBoxService 
{   
  private messageSource = new Subject<any>();
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}
  
  changeMessage(message: any)
  {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

}
```

**The supplying component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { StatusBoxService } from '../../services/status-box.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-live-summary',
  templateUrl: './live-summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./live-summary.component.css']
})

export class LiveSummaryComponent implements OnInit 
{

constructor(private data: StatusBoxService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
     this.data.changeMessage('hello world')   
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void
  {
    //this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**The receiving component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { StatusBoxService } from 'src/app/services/status-box.service';
import { ConfirmActionComponent } from '../confirm-action/confirm-action.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-status-box',
  templateUrl: './delete-status-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-status-box.component.css']
})
export class DeleteStatusBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription!: Subscription;
  selectedDevice = '';
  testy!: any;

  constructor(private form: FormBuilder, public dialog: MatDialog, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteStatusBoxComponent>, private data: StatusBoxService) 
  {
    //this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(param => this.testy = param) // doesn't work
    this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe((data: any) => 
      {
        this.testy = data;
      }); // doesn't work
  }

  DeleteStatusBoxForm = this.form.group({
    selectedDevice: ['']
  });

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    console.log(this.testy);
  }

  deleteStatusBox()
  {
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmActionComponent)
    //this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

In the receiving component I print out the testy variable which I assign to the incoming data when I subscribe to the `currentMessage` variable in the service.

Bur somehow when I `console.log()` the testy variable it displays undefined and I don't know why:

[image]

**How Components Interact:**

The *app-live-summary* component is a page that is part of a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` with other pages. The *app-live-summary* contains muliple other components.

One of those components contained inside the *app-live-summary* page is a *app-header*. This app-header component contains a button that when clicked opens up the *app-delete-status-box* component in the form of a modal pop up box.

The *app-live-summary* component also has some data which I would like to pass to pass to the *app-delete-status-box* when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your components used in this order:

```
<app-delete-status-box></app-delete-status-box>
<app-live-summary></app-live-summary>
```

you won't get any data since you're sending a value after app-delete-status-box component is instantiated and trying to console it on ngOnInit method which will only fire when your component is being initialized on view. Try to change the order and console the value changes on inside your subscription:

```
ngOnit(){
 this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe((data: any) => 
      {
        this.testy = data;
        console.log(this.testy)
      });
}
```

If app-delete-status-box is a dialog component, you can use `dialog.open(yourComponent, data)` method to send that value (call the service method there to fetch the values). More info on dialog here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: I had a look to see if I could work out the order however I'm not sure how I can tell. The live summary is a page which is part of a <router-outlet> that displays mny other components. The <app-delete-status-box></app-delete-status-box> is a modal box component that is loaded when the user clicks the remove button as part of a component on the live summart page.

Comment: I did try to change the order of imports in the app.module since the LiveSummary. page was being imported after the DeleteStatusBox but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Moving the console.log also made it so no output appeared on the console at all.

Comment: thanks for the clarification   @SneakyShrike. modals are initialized on view when they are clicked, so you're only subscribing when they are clicked (which is after a value is emitted) that's why it will be empty. for it to have a data, the other component needs to be initialized after you open the dialog. 
if it's dialog component, you can use dialog.open(yourComponent, data) method to send that value (call the service method there to fetch the values). More info on dialog here:   
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview Hope i was able to help a bit

Comment: I'll have a look, although I did just try to use a different component that's just a box in the live summary page to be the receiving component, but I got exactly the same undefined issue.

Comment: Oh my mistake, it did work in the other component that was just a box in the live summary. I just called the subscribe in the constructor and console logged inside the subscribe and i got my 'hello world'. If i try to do this in the Oninit it doesn't work, i get undefined. So I can try your suggestion regarding the modal component.

Comment: I managed to get it working using the dialog.open technique. If you want to update your answer to say what you said in the comments, I can mark the question as resolved and upvote. Thanks a lot!

Comment: my pleasure! @SneakyShrike i editted my answer . Thank you as well!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the component has not a good loading sequence.
If you move "console.log" in

```
this.subscription = this.data.currentMessage.subscribe((data: any) => 
  {
    this.testy = data;
    console.log(this.testy);
  });
```

It's works ?

In view, you can use AsyncPipe to get result with observable.

```
{{ testy$ | async }}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly moving the console.log also made it so no output appeared on the console at all, the same was true for the async. No output at all.

Comment: If you move subscription in ngOninit ?
And if you add a console.log in before this line this.data.changeMessage('hello world') do you have result console.log before or after the other console.log ?

Comment: So the console.log before the this.data.changeMessage('hello world') in the supplying component first displays in the console with a string. The second console log is being printed in the OnInit function (but outside of the subscribe) and displays undefined. The third console log is inside the subsribe (the subscribe is inside the Oninit) and displays nothing, not even an entry in the console.

Comment: Also if you read my other comments for Can Gyelans remarks as well as seeing my summary on component interaction added to my question it might help clarify.